# How to merge files line by line in bash

Tags: bash

My files look like

```
file0      file1      file2  
a           1          ##
a           1          ##

b           2          @@
b           2          @@
```

and I want to merge these files lines by lines, so it should look like

```
merged file  
a   
a       
1
1
##
##

b    
b
2
2
@@
@@
```

I mean, choose some lines for each file and merge them into one file.
I tried below bash script.

```
touch ini.dat
n=2
linenum=$(wc -l < file0)
iter=$((linenum/n))

for i in $(seq 0 1 $iter)
do
    for j in $(seq 0 1 2)
    do
            awk 'NR > '$(($i*$n))' && NR <= '$((($i+1)*$n))'' file"$j" > tmp
            cat ini.dat tmp > tmpp
            cp tmpp ini.dat
            rm tmpp
    done
done
```

It works fine, but takes too much time. Is there any efficient way?

Comment: see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice for discussion on using shell loops to process text

Comment: @Sundeep probably not related.

Comment: Do all input files have same number of lines?

Comment: @anubhava yes.They have same lines and format

Comment: does the empty line part of the data files and indicates where the record separator is?  Your script doesn't handle it though?

Comment: @karakfa Actual data file doesn't have that empty line. I just typed it to clarify where I seperate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Limiting Factors

Your script had two flaws which made it slow:

- A lot of files were created and copied. Especially the `... > tmp; cat ini.dat tmp > tmpp; cp tmpp ini.dat` could have been written as `... >> ini.dat`.
- To read the *i*-th line of a file, the script has to scan that file from the beginning until the *i*-th line is reached. If done repeatedly for *i* = 1, 2, 3, ..., *n* it will take *O*(*n*<sup>2</sup>). Reading the whole file once (*O*(*n*)) into an array and accesing the lines by indices (*O*(1)) only takes *O*(*n*).

## Pure Bash Solution

The following bash script does the job a bit faster. `linesPerBlock` corresponds to the parameter `n` from your script. The script will print as much blocks as possible. That is:

- Once the shortest input file was printed, the script terminates. Following lines from longer files will not be printed.
- If the shortest input file's number of lines is not divisible by *n*, the last lines (fewer than *n*) will be omitted.

```
#! /bin/bash

files=(file{0..2})
linesPerBlock=2

starts=(0)
maxLines=9223372036854775807 # bash's max. number
for i in "${!files[@]}"; do
    lineCount="$(wc -l < "${files[i]}")"
    (( lineCount < maxLines )) && (( maxLines = lineCount ))
    (( starts[i+1] = starts[i] + maxLines ))
    mapfile -t -O "${starts[i]}" -n "$maxLines" lines < "${files[i]}"
done

for (( b = 0; b < maxLines / linesPerBlock; ++b )); do
    for f in "${!files[@]}"; do
        start="${starts[f]}"
        for (( i = 0; i < linesPerBlock; ++i )); do
            echo "${lines[start + b*linesPerBlock + i]}"
        done
    done
done > outputFile
```

Answer (score 0):

This `awk` should do the job and will be much quicker that your shell script:

```
awk 'fn != FILENAME {
   fn = FILENAME
   n = 1
}
NF {
   a[FILENAME,n++] = $0
}
END {
   for(i=0; i<(n-1)/2; i++) {
      for(j=1; j<ARGC; j++)
         printf "%s\n%s\n", a[ARGV[j],i*2+1], a[ARGV[j],i*2+2];
      print ""
   }
}' file{0..2}

a
a
1
1
##
##

b
b
2
2
@@
@@
```

In a single line:

```
awk 'fn != FILENAME{fn=FILENAME; n=1} NF{a[FILENAME,n++]=$0} END{for(i=0; i<(n-1)/2; i++) { for(j=1; j<ARGC; j++) printf "%s\n%s\n", a[ARGV[j],i*2+1], a[ARGV[j],i*2+2]; print "" } }' file{0..2}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is another `awk`, not caching all contents

```
paste file{0..2} | awk -v n=2 '
                   function pr() {for(j=1;j<=NF;j++)
                                    for(i=0;i<n;i++) print a[i,j]}
                       {for(j=1;j<=NF;j++) a[c+0,j]=$j; c++}
               !(NR%n) {pr(); delete a; c=0}
                   END {pr()}'
```

if the number of lines is not divisible by n, it will fill up with empty lines.

Comment: Good idea to use `paste`. But don't have to make to sure not to use `\t` in any of the files?

Comment: in that case you should pick your own delimiter and set FS with that.